# Establecer "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF | ON" en Stored Procedure SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

buena tarde...
Tengo un error al querer ejecutar un Stored Procedure en SQL server, les muestro el codigo de mi SP:

```html
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spkof_DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus] AS    
begin    
   declare @dteIni        datetime,    
           @sProcesoNom   varchar(100),    
           @sMensaje      varchar(300),    
           @iRegHistoria  integer,    
           @iRegDelta     integer, 
           @iError        integer,      
           @iUpdate       integer,    
           @iInsert       integer = 0,
           @rowcount      integer = 0,
           @TimezoneName  varchar(max) = 'Central Standard Time (Mexico)';    
         
   set @dteIni = SWITCHOFFSET(getdate(), Datediff( MINUTE, getdate() at time zone @TimezoneName, getdate() )) 
   set @sProcesoNom = 'spKof_DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus'    
    
   -- Registra el inicio del proceso en la bitácora    
   insert into kofBitacora (ProcesoNom, FechaHoraIni, FechaHoraFin, MensajeDsc) values (@sProcesoNom, @dteIni, '99991231', 'INICIADO....')    
    
   -- Calcula la cantidad de registros a procesar
   
   set @iRegHistoria = (select count(*) from [cadsum].[DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus])    
   set @iRegDelta = (select count(*) from [dbo].[tmpDSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus])    
   
   set @sMensaje = ' registros: [ ' + convert(varchar(10), @iRegHistoria) + ' Historia; ' + convert(varchar(10), @iRegDelta) + ' Delta]' 
   update kofBitacora set MensajeDsc = 'Actualizando... ' + @sMensaje  where ProcesoNom = @sProcesoNom and FechaHoraIni = @dteIni    
  
  update H
     set 
                            --============= CAMPOS NO LLAVES =============
                            H.[STATUS_ID] = cast(N.[STATUS_ID] as varchar(8)),
                            H.[IDATE]     = convert(date, case when N.[IDATE] = '00000000' OR N.[IDATE] = ''  then '19000101' else N.[IDATE] end, 112),
                            H.[ITIME]     = cast(format(cast(case when isnumeric(N.[ITIME]) <> 1 or N.[ITIME] = '240000' then 0 else N.[ITIME] end as int), '00:00:00') as time),
                            H.[CANCELED]  = cast(N.[CANCELED] as varchar(1)),
                            H.[MAN_EXEC]  = cast(N.[MAN_EXEC] as varchar(1))
                            --============================================

   from [cadsum].[DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus] H inner join [dbo].[tmpDSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus] N 
                            --============= CAMPOS LLAVES ================
                            on  H.[TOURID]  = cast(N.[TOURID]  as varchar(12))
                            and H.[COUNTER] = cast(N.[COUNTER] as varchar(8))
                            --============================================

                            --============= CAMPOS DEFAULT ===============
                            and H.[MAND]     = cast(N.[MAND] as varchar(3))
                            and H.[Mandante] = cast(N.[Mandante] as varchar(3))
                            --============================================
   OPTION (LABEL = 'spKof_DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus_update01')


  -- Declara el @@RowCount
 
  select top 1 @rowcount = row_count
  from [sys].[dm_pdw_request_steps] s, [sys].[dm_pdw_exec_requests] r
  where r.request_id = s.request_id
  and row_count > -1
  and operation_type = 'OnOperation'
  and r.[label] = 'spKof_DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus_update01'
  order by r. [end_time] desc;

  
   select @iError = @@ERROR, @iUpdate = @rowcount
  
   update kofBitacora set MensajeDsc = 'Insertando... ' + @sMensaje  where ProcesoNom = @sProcesoNom and FechaHoraIni = @dteIni;  

     insert into [cadsum].[DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus]
     select 
                    
                    --============= CAMPOS LLAVES ================
                     cast([TOURID]  as varchar(12)) as [TOURID]
                    ,cast([COUNTER] as varchar(8))  as [COUNTER]
                    --============================================ 

                    --============= CAMPOS NO LLAVES =============
                    ,cast([STATUS_ID] as varchar(8)) as [STATUS_ID] 
                    ,convert(date, case when [IDATE] = '00000000' OR [IDATE] = ''  then '19000101' else [IDATE] end, 112) as [IDATE]
                    ,cast(format(cast(case when isnumeric([ITIME]) <> 1 or [ITIME] = '240000' then 0 else [ITIME] end as int), '00:00:00') as time) as [ITIME]   
                    ,cast([CANCELED]  as varchar(1)) as [CANCELED] 
                    ,cast([MAN_EXEC]  as varchar(1)) as [MAN_EXEC]
                    --============================================

                    --============= CAMPOS DEFAULT ===============
                    ,cast([MAND]     as varchar(3)) as [MAND]
                    ,cast([Mandante] as varchar(3)) as [Mandante]
                    --============================================

      
    
     from [dbo].[tmpDSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus] N
        where not exists 
        (select * from [cadsum].[DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus] H 
                         where 1 = 1
                         --============= CAMPOS LLAVES ================
                         and H.[TOURID]  = cast(N.[TOURID]  as varchar(12))
                         and H.[COUNTER] = cast(N.[COUNTER] as varchar(8))
                         --============================================

                         --============= CAMPOS DEFAULT ===============
                         and H.[MAND]     = cast(N.[MAND]     as varchar(3))
                         and H.[Mandante] = cast(N.[Mandante] as varchar(3))
                         --============================================
                         )
    OPTION (LABEL = 'spKof_DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus_insert01');

  select top 1 @rowcount = row_count
  from [sys].[dm_pdw_request_steps] s, [sys].[dm_pdw_exec_requests] r
  where r.request_id = s.request_id
  and row_count > -1
  and operation_type = 'OnOperation'
  and r.[label] = 'spKof_DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus_insert01'
  order by r. [end_time] desc;   

   select @iError = @iError + @@ERROR, @iInsert = @rowcount  
  
   If @iError <> 0  set @sMensaje = 'ERROR ' + convert(varchar(10), @iError) + 'al procesar ' + @sMensaje
   else 
   begin
        set @sMensaje = 'OK, registros procesados: [ ' +  
               convert(varchar(10), @iRegHistoria) + ' Historia; ' +        
               convert(varchar(10), @iRegDelta) + ' Delta; ' +       
               convert(varchar(10), @iUpdate) + ' Modificados; ' +       
               convert(varchar(10), @iInsert) + ' Nuevos]';      
   end

    update kofBitacora 
       set MensajeDsc = @sMensaje, 
          FechaHoraFin = SWITCHOFFSET(getdate(), Datediff( MINUTE, getdate() at time zone @TimezoneName, getdate() )) 
   where ProcesoNom = @sProcesoNom  and FechaHoraIni = @dteIni; 
 
 end

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
GO
```

Al ejecutar ese SP de la siguiente manera:

exec [dbo].[spkof_DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus]

Marca el siguiente error de insercion de datos de una tabla (**[dbo].[tmpDSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus]**) a otra tabla final (**[cadsum].[DSD_ST_STATUS_H-TourStatusHistoryRecordingTourStatus]**):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando sobre este error, encuentro a que se debe porque el numero de caracteres de mis datos es superior al tamaño de mi columna, pero mis datos son menores al tamaño de mis columnas.

Entonces por eso en el SP puse las funciones "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF" y "SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON" para anular el error que marca al ejecutarlo.

Pero marca el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quisiera saber es en donde puedo colocar estas funciones "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF" y "SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON" en mi SP para poder ejecutar correctamente mi SP.

Espero haberme explicado bien.
Cualquier cosa estaré al pendiente

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no creo que sea el camino que deberías de utilizar, porque si el motor te dice que el dato es más largo que lo que el contenedor, es porque es más largo (puede haber espacios u otros carácteres no imprimibles), esto lo puedes usar tal que:

```
Create table dbo.SetAnsi (id int identity(1,1), parametro varchar(5));
```

Ahora un procedure con Set Ansi_Warnings;

```
Create Procedure dbo.AddSetAnsi
(
@param varchar(10)
)
As
    BEGIN
        print 'cambio Ansi_Warnings OFF';
        SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
        
        INSERT INTO dbo.SetAnsi (parametro)
        Values (@param);
        print 'cambio Ansi_Warnings ON';
        SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
        
        SELECT * FROM dbo.SetAnsi;

    END
GO
```

Fíjate que están puestos en el cuerpo del procedure. Entre el `BEGIN` y el `END`.

Su ejecución:

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(10);
SET @VAR = '1234567890';
EXEC dbo.AddSetAnsi @var;
```

La salida de la ventana de mensajes:

[image: Res1]

La salida de la ventana de resultados.

[image: Res2]

Por tanto ha aplicado el truncamiento del parámetro pasado, utilizando `Set Ansi_Warnings On`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte!! se que no es el camino que deberia de tomar, solo que comprobando la data de las tablas, es el numero correcto del tamaño de la columna, etc.
Te agradezco tu aporte, si me funciono!!!